# Is there a way to debug through kubernetes source code using e2e/integration test?

Tags: debugging, integration-testing

I am fairly new to k8s community and am trying to get more familiar with k8s source code. I was wondering if it's possible to use IDE like goland to run/debug [kubernetes integration/e2e test](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/da962db2c4bcb2087a51fd0ee5f3635330d7d29f/contributors/devel/testing.md)?

For example, to run a specific integration test I can run the following in command line:

> make test-integration WHAT=./test/integration/pods GOFLAGS="-v" KUBE_TEST_ARGS="-run ^TestPodUpdateActiveDeadlineSeconds$"

Is it possible to set up debug config in goland so I can debug through TestPodUpdateActiveDeadlineSecondsthis?

Thanks!